# Angularjs + Phonegap Camera Plugin+ Facebook open graph

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, cordova, social-networking

I'm having a problem with trying to let my app users to share photos from their phone on facebook :

this is the object that I pass to facebook api

```
$scope.items = {
                    message:"",
}
```

when I make a photo on my device using phonegap camera plugin via my app, I get the actual uri of the photo that I made, the photo is being kept in cache, so then I take the photo's uri and assign it to the items object like this $scope.items.image = photoURI;

then I do that :

```
if($scope.items.message != "")
                    OpenFB.post('/me/feed', $scope.items)
                    .success(function(){
                        alert('Your message has been posted on facebook');
                        $scope.items.message = "";
                    }).error(function(data){
                        alert(data.error.message);
                    });
```

it immediately returns an error that the image url isn't being supported.

Actually, I think that I must upload it on facebook before, or maybe not, so any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either specify a public available URL, or upload the photo first to the user's photos, and use the `object_id` of this photo.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos/#publish

Comment: I also found that article before my lunch, so, thank you to help, gonna work on that now